# NodeJS - Javascript create object instance from String

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my Node.Js application (server side) I have to create an object instance (that is a class, so with `new MyClass()`) but MyClass is a `string`.

Its possible to create object instance from a String ? I've see that in browser side I can use `window`, but here I'm on server side...

I will need this because I will now the name of the class at run time, so I can't instantiate this object in "code".

Moreover, I can have several classes that need to be created in this way.
In short, I have a configuration file that explicit this kind of class, and I need to convert this string in a real JavaScript object.

Comment: I think that the factory pattern is what you are seeking for: essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#factorypatternjavascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute a JavaScript function when I have its name as a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With nodejs, `window` is "replaced" by `global`. So if your class is available in the global context, you can use `global["ClassName"]` to fetch it.

However, if you can, you may also consider the use of a dictionary of constructors. It is generally cleaner. Here is an example.

```
var constructors = {
   Class1: Class1,
   Class2: Class2
};

var obj1 = new constructors["Class1"](args);
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was in mind! My idea was to create an handler to manage all the classes in a Object like you showed me the factory. But 
I did not think it was possible to call new on it. You saved my life :D

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean

```
var myClass = Object.assign(new MyClass(), JSON.parse(classString));
```